# why laravel throw an exception when I use composer to create a laravel project?

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

After I use `composer create-project laravel/laravel` to create a laravel project,I can't run any composer command in this project.It will throw an exception like the pic as below :
[image]

But everything is normal when I use `git clone` to create a laravel project.
Is there anyway to deal with it ??? Is this happened because of the environment configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the  `composer -vvv command` command to show the debug info to debug this exception.
And you will see the detail execute infos include what caused this exception.
This exception shows because missing lib files.So I reinstall it correctly to solve this problem.